# If I join the Brotherhood and the Minutemen will Nick Valentine survive?

Tags: fallout-4

I am close to breaking in to the Institute. I know I will ally with the Minutemen (in the general) no matter what but I joined the Brotherhood of Steel, too. The Brotherhood said when I find a way to break in, go to them immediately. When I got the courser chip decoded, the Railroad said I should go to them first.

I want to help the Brotherhood, but I'm afraid that if I attack the Institute with the Brotherhood, that we will destroy the Railroad and the Institute. The only synth I want to live is Nick.

If I go with the Brotherhood, will they kill Nick in the end?

Answer (score 5):

Nick survives every ending. He will not be happy if you sided with the institute thou.

Comment: This seems likely, as he appears to play a major role in the Far Harbour DLC.

Answer (score 0):

I've completed the game allied with the Brotherhood. I can say for sure you will not be forced to kill Nick. Also you will not need to wipe out the Minutemen. The only companion you may kill is Deacon if he is not recruited.

I don't know if you can save him by recruiting him early, I didn't get Deacon.

Comment: There's another companion you will need to kill in order to finish the brotherhood questline. You skip that somehow? Maybe you can lie about it...

Comment: You can persuade the Elder to consider then companion dead and he will stay in the bunker. This can be done at the end of the quest when confronted by the Elder after spearing him and leaving the bunker.

Comment: You also have to kill him if you recruited him earlier. That happened to me.

Comment: There's an Institute specific companion that you end up killing if you side with anybody but the Institute.